# undo escape sequence "\" before unicode char

Tags: c#, string, unicode, char, wchar

I use a console program (cmd call) for translating a string from the standard input into a string in special Unicode characters, received from the standard output. The returning string in C# escapes the escaping backslash before the Unicode character.

How can I undo this escaping?

Example returning string =

```
stdout = "\\x284b\\x2817\\x2801\\x281d\\x2835 \\x281a\\x2801\\x281b\\x281e \\x280a\\x280d \\x2805\\x2815\\x280d\\x280f\\x2807\\x2811\\x281e\\x281e \\x2827\\x2811\\x2817\\x283a\\x2801\\x2813\\x2817\\x2807\\x2815\\x280e\\x281e\\x2811\\x281d \\x285e\\x2801\\x282d"
```

... but it should be

```
stdout = "\x284b\x2817\x2801\x281d\x2835 \x281a\x2801\x281b\x281e \x280a\x280d \x2805\x2815\x280d\x280f\x2807\x2811\x281e\x281e \x2827\x2811\x2817\x283a\x2801\x2813\x2817\x2807\x2815\x280e\x281e\x2811\x281d \x285e\x2801\x282d"
```

My trys to resove this problem by doing

```
var stdout2 = stdout.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

doesn't have effect.

Thanks 4 help.

Comment: How are you viewing the string? Are you paused in the debugger?

Comment: It doesn't have any effect because these double backslashes don't actually exist.  The debugger is trying to be too helpful, showing you the string the way you would write in C# code.  Use the text visualizer to see what the string *really* looks like.  Click the spyglass icon.

Comment: So I used the debugger to view this result. But the debug output:

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(stdout); `
Results in: _\x284b\x2817\x2801\x281d\x2835 …_

But it should display the braille characters like ⡋⠗⠁⠝⠵ ⠚⠁⠛⠞ ⠊⠍ ⠅⠕⠍⠏⠇⠑⠞⠞ ⠧⠑⠗⠺⠁⠓⠗⠇⠕⠎⠞⠑⠝ ⡞⠁⠭

Comment: Where has this `\xNNNN` string come from? I don't know of any string escaping format that uses backslash-x to represent a UTF-16 code unit. Many formats (JSON, C# source etc) use backslash-u.

Comment: @gmail user: yes - it seems to be impossible. I didn't find any solution yet

Comment: @bobince: the result comes from a console programm called liblouis and will be printed out to the console output --> stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it is easy and a little bit complex at the same time. I came to the solution by knowing that a `char` can be created out of an `integer`. So by knowing, that the coding of style '*\x284b*' indicates the hexadecimal value '*284B*' which is '*10315*' in decimal and therefore can be cast into a `char`. So I used these small functions to translate the coding into an `Int32` and from that into an internal `string` … voila

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the char from unicode hexadecimal string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="characterCode">The character code e.g. '\x2800'.</param>
/// <returns>the current available unicode character if available e.g. ' '</returns>
public static string GetCharFromUnicodeHex(String characterCode)
{

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(characterCode))
    {
        if (characterCode.StartsWith(@"\"))
        {
            characterCode = characterCode.Substring(1);
        }
        if (characterCode.StartsWith("x"))
        {
            characterCode = characterCode.Substring(1);
        }

        int number;
        bool success = Int32.TryParse(characterCode, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number);

        if (success)
        {
            return GetCharFromUnicodeInt(number);
        }
    }
    return String.Empty;
}


/// <summary>
/// try to parse a char from unicode int.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number">The number code e.g. 10241.</param>
/// <returns>the char of the given value e.g. ' '</returns>
public static string GetCharFromUnicodeInt(int number)
{
    try
    {
        char c2 = (char)number;
        return c2.ToString();
    }
    catch { }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
stdout = stdout.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

instead.

Comment: ok I know i had to writ this more clear. Yes that is wha I've done and it doesn't have effect

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to remove `\\` in the string. It should print as `\\x284b...`. If that's the case append string with `@`. Following code will print with `\\`

```
       string stdout = @"\\x284b\\x2817\\x2801\\x281d\\x2835 \\x281a\\x2801\\x281b\\x281e
       \\x280a\\x280d \\x2805\\x2815\\x280d\\x280f\\x2807\\x2811\\x281e\\x281e   
       \\x2827\\x2811\\x2817\\x283a\\x2801\\x2813\\x2817\\x2807\\x2815\\x280e\\x281e\\x2811
        \\x281d \\x285e\\x2801\\x282d";

        Console.Write(stdout);
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Not really. The console prog writes to the stdout a string like "\x284b". I read the stdout in C# and want to get the Unicode char "⡋" from the string. But C# escapes the "\" and do not recognize that this is a Unicode-code. How can I get this string as string of Unicode signs?

Comment: I tested in with VS 2010 and C#. It prints with the \\. Make sure you've @ applied

Comment: I don't understand why I have to use a @. I don't want to print the backslash as well as the double backslash. In the end I want to have ⡋⠗⠁⠝⠵ ⠚⠁⠛⠞ ⠊⠍ ⠅⠕⠍⠏⠇instead of \x284b\x2817\x2801\x281d\x2835 \x281a\x2801\x281b\x281e in my sysout or where ever I need.

Comment: It appears as square in your comment. But, if you want to remove the \\, just use the `Console.Write(stdout.Replace("\\",""));`

Answer (score 0):

> the result comes from a console programm called liblouis

Ah OK, LibLouis has its own curious non-standard string escape scheme, documented in section 3 [here](http://liblouis.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/liblouis.html). If you want to turn it into a raw unescaped Unicode string there are many backslash escape sequences you'll want to handle in addition to `\x`. Something like (not tested):

```
var escape = new Regex(@"\\(x[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}|y[0-9A-Fa-f]{5}|z[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}|.)");
var chars = new Dictionary<char, string> {
    { 'f', "\f" }, { 'n', "\n" }, { 'r', "\r" }, { 't', "\t" }, { 'v', "\v" },
    { 's', " " }, { 'e', "\x1B"}
};

var decoded_string = escape.Replace(encoded_string, match =>
    match.Length>2 ?
        Char.ConvertFromUtf32(
            int.Parse(
                match.Value.Substring(2),
                System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber
            )
        ) :
    chars.ContainsKey(match.Value[1]) ?
        chars[match.Value[1]] :
    match.Value.Substring(1)
);
```